# Bootstrap timepicker rendering issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, render, timepicker

Currently using the TimePicker from BootStrap which is shown in a modal widget below the main time display when clicked.

The issue being in IE8 the chevrons for the increasing/decreasing each part of the time picker do not render on load and need to be hovered over.

We have tried changing / adding a css class on load to force a redraw however this does not appear to resolve the issue, however the css changes do apply once we hover over the chevron.

Has anyone else come across this specifically in IE8 and has a solution?

Edit:

```
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.bootstrap-timepicker-widget')[0].className += '';
            $('.bootstrap-timepicker-widget .glyphicon-chevron-up').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('cg-fake');
            });
        }, 100);
```

is along the lines of our attempts to force IE8 to redraw once the widget is shown

Comment: Further reading is making this sound like a documented IE8 caveat.. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13863

Comment: please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" as it means something else.

Comment: sorry wasn't aware, changed approved.